# Generate Password Only If the DOM element is empty

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm a newbie and would really appreciate your help in figuring out how to solve a problem I'm having with this sample password generator code:

```
const characters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","~","`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=","{","[","}","]",",","|",":",";","<",">",".","?",
"/"];
let password = ""
let passwordLenght = 12;
let passEl = document.getElementById("pass-el")

function generatePass() {
for (let i = 0; i < passwordLenght; i++) {
    let char = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
    password += characters[char];
    passEl.textContent = password;
}
}

function resetPass() {
    password = ""; 
    passEl.textContent = password;
}
```

I'm simply looping through an array of available chars to generate a random pass. I'm aware Math Random is not a very secure option, but this is simply for exercise purposes.

The problem is that the following code will keep generating passwords and push them at the end of the passEl.texcontent, while I'd need that to stop.

I considered a condition (eg. if passEl.length is lower than passwordLength, then print it, otherwise, reset and print a new one from scratch), but I'm having problems implementing it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: on what situation does `generatePass()` gets called

Comment: @ITgoldman when a button is clicked (onclick="generatePass()")

Comment: Add a condition like `onclick="if (!document.querySelector('#pass-el').innerText.trim()) { generatePass() }"` to it or add the condition inside the generatePass() function.

Comment: it works @Christopher, may I ask why we're using trim here? From my understanding, we're checking if #pass-el doesn't contain any white space (meaning there's already a pass generated). Am I correct?

Comment: To prevent something lke `<div>\n</div>` for example. The line break would count as innerText but isn't shown.